# ID column as a link to detailed view

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am trying to make my first column, which is the ID column clickable to go to a detailed view.  I had it working with normal tables as:

```
{% for tickets in tickets %}
...
<td><a href="{{tickets.get_absolute_url}}">{{tickets.id}}</a> </td>
...
{% endfor %}
```

What I have now using django-tables2 is this:

```
class TicketsTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Tickets
        fields = ("id", "subject", "desc", )
        id = tables.LinkColumn('tickets.get_absolute_url', tickets.id)
```

Pretty sure this is way off.  I am using a slug field named 'slug' for the different links.  I am still pretty new to this so I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: I'm getting closer I think.  Changed the linkcolumn line to:    id = tables.LinkColumn('ticket_detail', args=[A('pk')])

The problem is nothing I change or do has any affect on what is seen so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that worked was:

```
#tables.py
import django_tables2 as tables
from ticker.apps.ticket.models import Tickets
from django_tables2.utils import A

class TicketsTable(tables.Table):
id = tables.LinkColumn('ticket_detail', args={A("slug")})
subject =tables.Column()
```

Comment: what is slug here so we understand?

Comment: The slug is just an automatically generated slug of Table.title